# gettig value of dropdown to the js code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on the angularjs application.I want the selected value from dropdown list in the angular controller. Please advice.Below is the code.

```
<select>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>
```

js code:

```
myApp.controller('myController', function ($rootScope,$scope) {
//business logic
$rootScope.selectedValue='red';//I want the value of the dropdown selected, by default it is first option red
})
```

The above controller called when the page loads, how to assign the value selected from the dropdown to the $rootScope variable of the controller.

Comment: A couple of points - 1) don't use primitive values as your model, wrap them in objects 2) do you really need to use `$rootScope` instead of just `$scope`?

Comment: @KarlReid - Yes , i want to assign the value to $rootscope.Any suggestios?

Comment: Why do you want to use `$rootScope`? I suggest you accept @anoop's answer, it answers your question, and his updated fiddle in the comments shows a much improved way of structuring your model, and also fulfills your requirement of `alert`ing the changed value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<select ng-model="selectedValue">`

http://jsfiddle.net/fufpxyub/

and, as suggestion don't use primitive prop in `rootscope`. see
[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x4300x3w/) and if possible avoid rootscope., use only $scope of controller.

Comment: @user222 no, this answer works fine. The `alert` only happens once, before the selection is made, why would you expect it to show anything but the default value? You can see clearly that `{{selectedValue}}` is changing anyway, you don't need the `alert`.

Comment: @user222: you need to write some method for `alert` and call it on every model change. [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x4300x3w/), also don't use primitive prop for rootScope., and if possibel avoid rootscope.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `ng-model` to `select` tag.

**Example:**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.showPopup=function(){
    alert($scope.MyData);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="MyData">
    <option disabled selected value>-- select an option --</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  </select>
  <a class="btn btn-primary add-contract-button pull-right" ng-click="showPopup()">Click to show selected value</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code.

In HTML, change your select as below,

```
<select ng-model="colorSelected" ng-change="selectColor(colorSelected)">
 <option value="red">Red</option>
 <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>
```

In JS or Controller, access it as below,

```
myApp.controller('myController', function ($rootScope,$scope) {
   $rootScope.selectedValue=$scope.colorSelected;
   $scope.selectColor = function(colorSelected){
        // use the colorSelected and set your alerts or basically handle anything
   }
})
```

Comment: Mac - Please see your code updated in http://jsfiddle.net/fufpxyub/4/. I'm not getting the alert with updated value and i want the first option to be selected by default.Appreciate your help.

Comment: @user222 Do you want an alert on change of the dropdown values or ?. If you want to capture on change of the dropdown values, please check up updated answer

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML write this code:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
<select ng-model="selectedValue">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>
</div>
```

And in JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myController', function ($rootScope,$scope) {
//business logic
$rootScope.selectedValue='red';//I want the value of the dropdown selected, by default it is first option red
})
```